# Are PGP Universal keys compatible with the openPGP standard?

Tags: linux, centos, gpg, pgp

I'm having issues importing a PGP Universal Public key on a system that supports openPGP. Are these two different standards/formats? Should they be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wikipedia article on [PGP Compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#Compatibility):

"As PGP evolves, versions that support newer features and algorithms are able to create encrypted messages that older PGP systems cannot decrypt, even with a valid private key. Therefore it is essential that partners in PGP communication understand each other's capabilities or at least agree on PGP settings."

You need to make sure that the key was created using an algorithm your openPGP implementation can handle.